# Setting diffuse map of material in 3ds max using C++

Tags: plugins, bitmap, 3dsmax

I am developing an utility plugin for 3dsMax 2013 and 2014 in C++. In this, I need to set a bitmap to the diffuse map of the currently selected object's material. I tried the following code, file name is showing near to the diffuse map in material editor but the image is not applied to the material as well as on clicking the View image button in Bitmap Parameters rollout is also not showing any image.

```
Bitmap* bmap;
BitmapInfo bmap_info(L"D:\\misc\\licenseplates.jpg");
// Load the selected image
BMMRES status;
bmap = TheManager->Load(&bmap_info, &status);

for( int i = 0; i < GetCOREInterface()->GetSelNodeCount(); ++i )
{
    INode *node = GetCOREInterface()->GetSelNode(i);
    // Get the material from the node
    Mtl *m = node->GetMtl();
    if (!m) return; // No material assigned

    StdMat* std = (StdMat *)m;

    // Access the Diffuse map
    BitmapTex *tmap = (BitmapTex *)std->GetSubTexmap(ID_DI);

    // No map assigned
    if (!tmap) 
    {
        tmap = (BitmapTex*)NewDefaultBitmapTex();
    }

    tmap->SetBitmap(bmap);
    tmap->SetBitmapInfo(bmap_info);
    tmap->ReloadBitmapAndUpdate();
    tmap->fnReload();

    std->SetSubTexmap(ID_DI,tmap);
    std->SetTexmapAmt(ID_DI,1.0f,0);
    std->EnableMap(ID_DI, TRUE);
}
```

Do I need to set some other parameters also to set the map?

[image]

[image]

Comment: you have some weird signs in your path, look at the first picture. possibly some unicode issue. Make sure the path is set correctly, and that the path in the box displays as it should.

Comment: It is not weird sign. I am using japanese OS so slash is represented using that sign. I tried displaying the bitmap with that path using Display function and the image is correct.

Comment: Ok, I did not know this.

Just a quick question - Do you use nitrous viewport?
Does it work with opengl \ direct-3d driver for 3dsmax?

Comment: No i am not using nitrous viewport. When i restart 3ds Max I can find the bitmap displayed in material editor.I am unaware whether I should do something more to display in material editor.

Comment: Instead of calling setBitmap and setBitmapInfo , when I used setMap it is working now.But i am not sure whether this is the correct method. `btmap->SetMap(bmap_info.GetAsset());` . Thanks.